# Simultaneous motion equation

Tags: physics

A car travels in a straight line. Taking: 15 seconds to travel 220m And 10 seconds to travel the next 220m. What is the acceleration. (Acceleration is constant)

I have tried using motion equations to simultaneously solve the question, but seem to be going round in circles.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Are we assuming that the car's acceleration is constant?  (I hope so because without knowing that I don't think we have a hope of solving the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Try solving $s=\frac{at^2}{2}+v_0t$ for $a, v_0$ with $s=220, t=15$ and with $s=440, t=25$.  That gives you two linear equations in two unknowns.